# PHP array data used in javascript graph - codeigniter

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

I am using API data in a model which is passed through to a controller then to view. In one particular instance I need to do a foreach() loop but in javascript to get the data I need, please see below how I've done it.

I know this is bad practice but wanted to know what the best practice is to achieve this so I know going forward.

```
categories: [<?php foreach($champ_name as $champ_id => $stat_value) {
               foreach ($stat_value as $cn => $cs) {
                   if($champ_id != 0) {
                       echo '"'.$cn.'",';
                   }
               } 
            } ?>]
```

Thanks for looking/helping.

(PS. the above does work but I know is not the right way)

Comment: use json_encode() instead of hand-building fragile strings...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `json_encode()` to convert it into an object or array that Javascript can use.

```
categories: <?php echo json_encode($myThing); ?>
```

For your use, you would still need your foreach logic to build an array to be json encoded.

If you build the array manually like in your question, you need to be mindful over special characters from breaking the array and causing syntax errors. For example if any of your `$cn` contained a double quote, it would produce a syntax error. The benefit of json encoding it is that any special characters will be taken care of without you having to handle them.

Example:

```
$arr = array('abc', 3, 'te"xt', 6);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Outputs

```
["abc",3,"te\"xt",6]
            ^ qoute has been automatically escaped
```

Comment: Cool this is very helpful - I will do this when I get home. So after encoding it into json, would I just do a javascript foreach just like I have done above?

Comment: Yes, the JSON is valid javascript syntax so you can echo it directly into Javascript code and work with it as normal (be sure to assign it to a variable).